# How to reset an accounts password in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, passwords, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to reset a password with the accounts packages.

**recover.html :**

```
<template name="recoverPassword">
  <div class="main-page">
    <div class="profile-container">
      <center>
        <div id="warning"></div>
        <div id="success"></div>
        {{#if resetPassword}}
        <form id="resetPasswordForm" method="post">
            <input id="resetPasswordPassword" name="password" placeholder="New Password" type="password" >
            <input id="resetPasswordPasswordConfirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm" type="password" >
            <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Reset">
        </form>
        {{else}}
        <form id="sendEmail">
          <div class="log-classic">
            <div class="show-no-error">
              <input class="log-upper-box" type="email" id="recover-email" placeholder='{{_ "global.emailHolder"}}' required>
            </div>
            <div class="bt-act-in">
              <input type="submit" class="btn bt-signin" value="{{_ "recover.sendMail"}}"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        {{/if}}
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**recover.js :**

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.recoverPassword.rendered = function(){
    if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken){
      Session.set('resetPassword', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
    }
  }

  Template.recoverPassword.helpers({
    resetPassword: function(){
      return Session.get('resetPassword') || false;
    }
  });

  Template.recoverPassword.events({
    'submit #sendEmail': function(event, template){
      event.preventDefault();
      template.find('#warning').innerHTML = "";
      template.find('#success').innerHTML = "";
      var email = template.find('#recover-email').value.trim();
      Accounts.forgotPassword({email: email}, function(err) {
        if (err){
          if (err.message === 'User not found [403]') {
            template.find('#warning').innerHTML = "There is no account registered with this email!";
          }else{
            console.log(err.message);
            template.find('#warning').innerHTML = "We are sorry but something went wrong.";
          }
        }else{
          template.find('#success').innerHTML = "An email has been sent";
        }
      });
    },
    'submit #resetPassword': function(e, t) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var password = t.find('#resetPasswordPassword').value;
      var passwordConfirm = t.find('#resetPasswordPasswordConfirm').value;
          console.log("pwd : " + password);
      if (true){
        Accounts.resetPassword(Session.get('resetPassword'), password, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            template.find('warning').innerHTML = "We are sorry but something went wrong.";
          } else {
            console.log("wesh");
            template.find('success').innerHTML = "Your password as been updated!";
            Session.set('resetPassword', null);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The recoverPassword template is included in my /splash page.
When I enter an unvalid email, I do well have the message indicating the email doesnt exists. Otherwise, a mail is sent with this message :

```
Hello,

To reset your password, simply click the link below.

http://mywebsite.herokuapp.com/#/reset-password/a7jr8WgGNRSJYHQg5x4vQhUn_qZSZEDxeJEtBgdjugD

Thanks.
```

Then I click on the link, and get to the splash page. Then the url change from the one I clicked on to  /splash (in other ords, the token disapear from the url bar of the browser).

The template correctly change, I type the new password, and then I had to disable Adblock to make it works. So did I, the adblock related erreor get out, but now, when I submit the form with the new password, nothings happens, and the accounts password keep unchanged :/

Of course, I've looked for some tips / documentation on the web, but nothing helped me to get further.

Could someone helps me as soon as possible ?

Thanks a lot,

David

Answer (score 0):

User The Function Like

```
  Accounts.changePassword(OldPass, NewPass,function (err) {});
```